# where is the entry point for a Python Package?

Tags: python-3.x, package, project, document

I learn how to explore Python package. Sometime I cannot find the entry-point of this package.

For example:

https://github.com/thunlp/OpenNE/tree/pytorch/src/openne

The online materials tell me that I can find the entry point in the `setup.py`. However, for this project, the `setup.py` does not have the entry point.

Given this package and assume the **
README.md  is missing**, how can I explore the package? like how I can know that I can use

`python -m openne --model gcn --dataset cora --sparse --no-save`.

Can someone give me step-by-step to how to explore an python package?

Many Thanks

Comment: That would be `__main__.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think "`if __name__ == "__main__":` is entry point